How do I get back on track in my studies after falling behind due to hopelessness of making in academia
I feel utterly lost. I performed decently in my  physics bachelor studies (GPA of ~3.6), while being a chronic procrastinator and yet finishing in 6 semesters. However now in my master's I've fallen quite far behind (about a year with a GPA of ~2.7). It was my childhood dream to become a physicist and "striving to be a physicist" became somewhat of an identity. I was quite worried if I was intelligent enough to study physics before uni. When I realized how hard the academic career path would be and stiff the competition would be my dreams started to seem out of reach. I felt like I will probably not measure up to the competition and I lost motivation to study. Last year I broke up with my girlfriend. I started going to therapy due to the abusive dynamics. All of that really led me to slack off in my studies and now I'm more worried than ever of not getting into a phd program or even making it in academia. I feel like a failure if I'm being honest. Until today I haven't opened my student card with my progress out of shame/anxiety in months. I don't really know how to get back on track. I want to become a researcher but I worry if I'm intelligent and good enough, especially now after having slacked off in my studies.

Very few people "make it" in academia, and "making it" isn't necessarily a particularly good mark of intelligence or overall life success. It sounds like you should spend some time broadening your definition of success and learning about alternative careers rather than putting all your eggs in a very fragile basket that carries an explicit note about being suitable for very few eggs.

Intelligence is only of the many predictors of success in academia, and probably not even the most important one. If I were you, I would worry less about intelligence and more about other factors ("being a chronic procrastinator", "I lost motivation to study"), which, unlike intelligence, you have much more control over.

@AdamPřenosil - as one of the founders of SE said, you have to be smart and get things done.

I always wanted to get a PhD, but when honest with myself, I found that I didn't personally want to deal with some of the aspects of working on a PhD that required a lot of personal discipline.  I know myself.  I'm not a very disciplined person--I need deadlines to create urgency.  It's not about not being intelligent; I simply don't want to do what is necessary to be successful in academia.  Instead of worrying about not being the person "I wanted to be", I reframed it such that I consider myself pragmatic, and I don't want this goal badly enough to change who I am.  For many years, I was upset by this "failure", but by reframing things this way, it was very freeing for me--I'm now focused on the person I am willing to work towards.
Instead, I found that what worked for me very well was to be a staff member at a university.  I am surrounded by faculty every day, which is actually tremendously wonderful--I get to have access to world-class minds all the time.  I also have personal relationships with many faculty, unlike students and postdocs--I can say more than 40 PIs at my school across many disciplines know me by name and are aware of the impact I personally have on research in the nine years I have had my job.  I also get to take classes in my areas of interest for very little money.  When I got my teaching degree (paid for by my employer), one of my letters of recommendation came from a PI that I provided grants support for.  (I asked him to write a recommendation that was about my work ethic; not my area of study.)  Not for nothing, but we also pay entry level people better than most postdocs get paid: Research Administrator Salary
I wish we could attract more folks with a science background into our open jobs, but many people with science degrees think "admin work" is a "step down" from academic work.  My job is incredibly challenging, highly rewarding, and it's within academia.  I am the lifeline for research where I work.  I learn how regulations work, how to get research done--it's a form of project management.  I take the burden off of PIs so that they spend their time doing research instead of paperwork or worrying about their finances. I once had a PI thank me 3 years after a proposal got awarded for the work I put into advising that PI on how to get funded.  He pointed out that my work helped provide jobs to several people.  Sure, I won't have publications with my name on it, but I do have people who thank me for what I do on a nearly daily basis.  Why define success so narrowly?  I have tremendous meaning in my work.
Broaden how you consider "working in academia", and you may find there are even better choices than where you are today.  If you understand some level of science, you could be a tremendous asset to a PI in terms of project management, lab management, or research administration -- all jobs that are becoming more important as the world moves towards applied research projects funded by sponsors like DARPA, IARPA, ARPA-H, and ARPA-E.  We need more scientists to consider administration.
At this point, I have been taking college classes from my employer for the last 15 years as a way of personal development--but getting my PhD?  I wouldn't leave my job for that now, not even if I were "fully funded".  I'm in the right place--my younger dream was naive and based on incomplete information, and so I let it go to find a new form of happiness.  However you end up, I hope you find your own form of success too--based on who you are now, not who you were as a child.

You seem to be doing the right thing in seeing a counsellor about the mental aspects. Don't let that end too soon. Work with them or someone else about procrastination. A change in study habits can help. Starting projects and assignments as soon as given, rather than near deadlines can help for many.
I suggest talking to one or more trusted professors about how you can get back on track and what might be blocking you. If the scale of your classes is small enough that professors recognize you it can help. This is the sort of thing for office visits, though, not email.
Slacking off might possibly be a sign of clinical depression. Counsellors and even doctors might be needed if that is the case.

When I realized how hard the academic career path would be and stiff the competition would be my dreams started to seem out of reach. I felt like I will probably not measure up to the competition
I want to become a researcher but I worry if I'm intelligent and good enough
The answer to the first half of the first one is that "Yeah, it is a bit more difficult than learning the phrase 'Paper or plastic', but still completely doable given time, patience, and perseverance. Just don't expect fast progress, especially in the beginning: it won't happen, and you have to learn to live with that. However, do not concentrate on how slow you are and how much is left to cover; instead celebrate each mark on the route already covered and you'll reach some summits eventually.
The answer to the second half of the first one is that "There always is a bigger fish in the pond". So, instead of comparing yourself with others at every step (you'll lose such comparison more often than not no matter at what stage and level you are just because coming to each next level brings you in direct contact with people who have reached it before you and they become your "peer benchmark" for some time, and if you look one level up from there, you'll feel totally inferior), compare yourself with yourself a year ago. If you lose that comparison, then you are on the wrong track indeed. But if you devote some decent time and effort to your dreams, you'll see some progress every time.
The answer to the last one is that unless you have some irreparable brain defect, you are both intelligent and good enough to join the workforce and become a useful part of it, but unless you are a genius, you are not good enough to make some really noticeable difference just by yourself. Remember that in every group of people, physicists being no exception, half are below the median and that any point on the real line has Lebesgue measure zero, but if you remove that half from the group or all points from the line, the group will lose a noticeable portion of its strength and the line will disappear entirely.
These are as honest answers as you can possibly get.
In all other respects you've got a good advice from Buffy already.
Just my two cents.
